# MySQL never completes query with a subquery, but completes when queries are run separately

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query that never finishes:

```
SELECT modelId, `timestamp` FROM thread_view WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT max(id) FROM thread_view
   WHERE viewerId = 1 AND modelType = 'LEASE' AND modelId IN 
   (15,615,618,660) GROUP BY modelId);
```

When I run just the subquery, it completes in 12ms and returns two ids. When I hardcode those 2 ids in place of the subquery, the outerquery returns two rows and completes in 0.3ms.

As you can see, both parts of the query run incredibly quickly and it's not like we're dealing with a lot of data here.  When I run the EXPLAIN:

[image: results of EXPLAIN]

The explain didn't reveal any problems to me.  Is this just a bug with MySQL?

EDIT: mysql --version gives:  mysql  Ver 8.0.25 for macos11.3 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

EDIT #2: As requested, here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `thread_view` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewerId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `modelType` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `modelId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `viewerId_modelType_modelId` (`viewerId`,`modelType`,`modelId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50582 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: Would you please update the question with the text of the `CREATE VIEW` statement and the `CREATE TABLE` statements (or others) associated with any underlying objects accessed by the `VIEW`?

Comment: Notice the `dependent subquery` in the explain plan.  That's often the reason for a performance issue.  That suggests either a bug or your SQL isn't representative or we don't have enough detail in the question.  Those unqualified column references should always be resolved by the nearest object.  In this case, you have one object, the view.  So there really should *NOT* be any correlated / dependent behavior in the SQL you showed.  Maybe there's something in the hidden `VIEW` definition causing this.  Hard to tell without that detail.

Comment: sorry it's misleading, but thread_view is not actually a VIEW, it is just an ordinary table.  Also, this is not a "performance issue", the query will never complete no matter how long it runs -- and there are not a lot of rows.

Comment: Ok. That's fine.  Please show that definition (text of the `CREATE TABLE`).  I don't see any reason for `DEPENDENT` behavior.  Are you sure this is the "exact" SQL?

Comment: @JonArmstrong Added!

Comment: I got the sql statement by doing a "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"

Comment: Also, please correct the SQL in the question.  There's a typo.  I'm guessing there's other missing / mistyped detail.  That SQL is invalid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236263/discussion-between-satnam-and-jon-armstrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is really to grab the greatest timestamp per model (also noted by @Shaharyar):

```
SELECT modelId
     , MAX(`timestamp`)
  FROM thread_view
 WHERE modelId IN (15,615,618,660)
   AND viewerId = 1
   AND modelType = 'LEASE'
 GROUP BY modelId
;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you instead phrase this using window functions. I'm not 100% sure that this is equivalent (you don't explain the data or what your query is supposed to be doing).

But assuming that `id` is unique, then try:

```
select t.*
from (select  t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by modelId order by id desc) as seqnum
      from thread_view t
      where viewerId = 1 and
            modelType = 'LEASE' and
            modelId in (15, 615, 618, 660)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that does seem to give the same answer as my query without freezing.  The purpose of this table is to track when users are viewing certain pages or models and then to quickly be able to  get the last timestamp they viewed a given set of models.

Comment: @satnam if you want to get `last timestamp` for each model, why not do `max(timestamp)`? Rather than selecting the `id` first, and then selecting the `timestamp` against that `id`

Comment: @Shaharyar an interesting thought, but I'm not quite sure what that would look like -- do you have an example query?

Comment: ```SELECT modelId, MAX(`timestamp`) FROM thread_view WHERE modelId IN (15,615,618,660) AND viewerId = 1 AND modelType = 'LEASE' GROUP BY modelId;
```